# Why use more than one endpoint in a Rebus system?

Tags: rebus

In a Rebus service bus, there is a single [message transport queue](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Transport) per endpoint.  It is possible for an endpoint to handle more than one message, and it is possible to have only a single endpoint in a system.

Other than the throughput of messages, what reasons are there to use more than a single endpoint in a Rebus service bus system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question! :) There can be many reasons why you might want to have several Rebus endpoints active at the same time.

An obvious reason is that you might want to host the endpoints in separate processes so you can update them independently of each other. But since this reason is pretty obvious, I assume you are thinking about *reasons one might want to host multiple Rebus endpoints in the same process*.

Let me just mention a few(*):

#### Concurrency requirements

One endpoint might be hosting data that experiences contention and therefore does not benefit from being able to process messages concurrently - this endpoint will probably have only a few threads and low parallelism, possibly 1/1.

Another endpoint might be doing stream-based data processing (e.g. loading blobs from one place into another, downloading data from web services, etc.), which can be done with very high throughput and low resource requirements with one single thread and a high level of parallelism - e.g. 1/20.

Yet another endpoint might be doing a lot of serialization/deserialization, which is usually CPU-bound, and therefore might benefit from running on a many-core box with many worker threads and matching parallelism - e.g. 10/10.

As you can see, the type of tasks performed by an endpoint can call for a configuration that matches the nature of the tasks.

#### SLAs

One endpoint might be designated for processing low-priority background stuff, like e.g. moving data to cold storage, optimizing storage of historic data, etc.

Another endpoint might be processing messages where low latency is the most important quality attribute.

If these two were using the same queue, the low-priority background stuff could sometimes clog up the queue, hindering low-latency processing of the other messages.

#### Logical separation

I have many times started out by hosting several Rebus endpoints in the same process because it was easy to deal with during development, while keeping the endpoints separate because they were implementing different business functions.

This way it is easy to physically break them apart some time later on, allowing for a higher degree of separation and independence.

---

(*) Udi Dahan works with the concepts "business components" and "autonomous components" where the first one is an implementation of a business capability and the second one is what business components are decomposed into, mostly for technical reasons.

I guess you could say that the first two reasons I mentioned are separate endpoints for "autonomous component" reasons, whereas the third is separation because things belong to different business components.

Udi keeps a pretty strict view of these concepts that is completely orthogonal to how the system is physically composed, but I almost always end up with pretty high convergence between logical separation and physical separation.

Comment: Thanks Mogens, but, err...I don't think I asked that question.  Perhaps I'm not seeing this right, but endpoints can share the same queue, right?  I was wondering about why bother to use different queues :)

Comment: What do you mean by "endpoints can share the same queue"? If two different bus instances are receiving messages from the same queue, only one of them will get each message

Comment: Ooops - I didn't realise that!  My Rebus systems thus far have always been in single endpoints.  Let me see if I can adjust the question so that your answer is retained. :)

Comment: When using MassTransit you can configure the types that will be consumed by a certain endpoint and that will create one queue per endpoint. The only way to achieve that with Rebus is by configuring another Bus instance?

Comment: If you want to consume from multiple queues, then yes that requires multiple bus instances. But it's totally fine with Rebus to consume different types of messages from the same queue, so in many cases, why bother?